# Codeigniter - remove blank lines from my rendered views

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have the following code in a view:

```
<div>
    <p>Some text here</p>
    <?= $content ?>
    <p>..another paragraph here</p>
</div>
```

Now if the `$content` variable is an empty string I get:

```
<div>
    <p>Some text here</p>

    <p>..another paragraph here</p>
</div>
```

What do I need to do to prevent this blank line from being added to my HTML?

I am looking for a solution that preserves my code formatting both in my view file and also in the HTML that is rendered to the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Open and close your PHP tags before your new lines so that the white-space is in PHP's scope and is therefore ignored and not output to the browser.

```
<p>Some text here</p><?php 
echo $content;
?><p>..another paragraph here</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt, but I was looking for a solution that would preserve my code formatting in my view file and also in the rendered HTML...

Comment: @freshest, This is the way it's done. As Matt said, if the whitespace is outside of the php tags, then it will be output to the browser. The only other way of doing this is to totally change the way you are using your views and go to a templating system ( a pretty dramatic change, to be rid of white space ). I'd like to know, what is the push for the same formatting? Shouldn't you be compressing your html before you push it to the browser anyway?

Comment: @swatkins, because the front end designers I am working with want the HTML rendered in the browser to be properly formatted.

Comment: Fair enough. One thing you could do is to use the output buffer and strip any extra lines before outputting to the browser. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 0):

If you should not work with CI's Template Parser, you can choose a full template-system.
I'm using [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) with CI, and works well (for me). Smarty has [strip function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.strip.tpl) which makes similar what you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
<p>Some text here</p>
<?php 
if($content != "") 
echo $content;
?>
<p>..another paragraph here</p>
```

You just put a conditional statement there.

Comment: This results in 2 new lines being added regardless.